# Filtering List View by Current User Email

Tags: list-view, user-profile, powerapps-forms

We have a Power app which feeds into a SharePoint list when users submit a form on the app. We don't use the 'People Field' when building apps as they are complicated and cause a few issues. So instead we use office 365 to grab the users info and save that in the relevant Field.

My question is, can I filter the list by the current user based on an email address in a field in the list rather than using the 'People' field?

Thanks,
Helen

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right thing. Using User ID (email) instead of the weird people field type is what I was doing as well. Many do the same.

Of course you can filter any list by an email in Power Apps. Filtering my email is not different from filtering by any other string-based field. Sample steps:

1. [Add Office 365 Users connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/).
2. Get current user's email like so

```
Office365Users.MyProfile().Mail
```

[image]

3. Now you can filter your SharePoint lists by email:

```
Filter('My SharePoint list', 'Email'= Office365Users.MyProfile().Mail)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using **Current User Filter** under **Filters** category. Then connect this Web Part with the main List View Web Part.

This has been described in details at [FILTER A VIEW BY “ME” WITHOUT A PEOPLE COLUMN](https://wonderlaura.com/2011/03/23/filter-a-view-by-me-without-a-people-column/)

Comment: Matiur, I could be wrong, but I think the question is about Power apps. The webparts you are suggesting have nothing to do with the Power Platform.

Comment: "Filtering List View by Current User Email" - I think OP is asking to filter list view in SharePoint.